# TypeError: Cannot read property 'any' of undefined React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, typeerror

I'm new to React and I'm trying to make small app by following a Udemy tutorial. The application contains a form. When I import [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) library into my project, I got the below console error.

[image] 
[image]

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "16.3.2",
    "react-countdown-now": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "16.3.2",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^3.2.0",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux-form": "^4.1.3",
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3"
  }
```

post_new.js contains the form.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

class PostsNew extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <h3>Create a new post</h3>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Title</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Categories</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control"/>
                </div> 
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>Content</label>
                    <textarea className="form-control"/>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>    
        );
    }
}
export default reduxForm(
    {
        form: 'PostsNewForm',
        fields: ['title','categories','content']
    }
)(PostsNew);
```

also imported `redux-form` in reducers _> index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import PostReducer from './reducer_posts';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  posts: PostReducer,
  form: formReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: Try updating your redux-form. You are using version 5 n v6 already out there. https://redux-form.com/6.7.0/docs/migrationguide.md/

Comment: If you had no errors till you imported redux-form it must some compatibility issues with the version of redux-form you have. Try changing the version.'

Comment: I have updateed redux-form version in to v7.now it's `"redux-form": "^7.3.0"`.but error is still there .

Comment: It sounds like you are, at some point, using an object and trying to read they key `any`. This is pretty common when you attempt to access a prop in a nested object like `this.props.data.any` where `this.props.data` is, at some point, `undefined`

Answer (score 2):

Use version 5.3.6.
It will definitely solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I ones had same error. How I resolved it was to upgrade the redux-form to v5.2.6. Then stop the server in your terminal using Ctrl +c, run npm i to bring in redux -form dependences. then restart your project.

Comment: I do not think there is a `redux-form` v5.2.6.

Comment: You are correct, I meant to say redux-form: "^5.3.6". thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0):

Installing updates using package-manager is not enough.
You need to reinstall your localhost after updating redux-form.
using:

- ***Ctrl + 'C'***
- ***npm i***
- ***npm start***